# Sending image through sockets not receiving fine

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to send a jpg image from a client process to a server via `sockets`. The image contains binary data so I want to do it on a low-level programming basis using `reads` and `writes`. I'm also sending the image data in iterations of 100 bytes.

This is the code I've done, which is not sending the image identically as I want:

**CLIENT**

```
void send_image(char *path, char *filename, int socket) {

    int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY); //I open the file of the image.jpg

    int n = 1;

    while (n > 0) {
        char img_data[100];
        n = read(fd, img_data, 100); //sending 100 bytes of image each iteration till n=0 (end of file)

        if (!n) break;

        int sending = 1;
        write(socket, &sending, sizeof(int)); //Tell the client the image still has data to send

        write(socket, img_data, strlen(img_data));

        usleep(250);
    }

    sending = 0; //Tell the server the image has been fully sent
    write(socket, &sending, sizeof(int));

    close(fd);
}
```

**SERVER**

```
void receiving_image(char *path) {

    int receiving = 0;
    int j=0;
    char *image_data = NULL; //Variable to store all the image data

    read(socket, &receiving, sizeof(int)); //Reads that the client is going to send an image

    while (receiving) {

        char data[100]; //Variable that stores partial data (100 bytes) of an image on each iteration 
        read(socket, data, 100);

        image_data = realloc(image_data, (j + strlen(data)) * sizeof(char)); //Readjust the size of the main image data.
      
        for (int i=0; i<(int) strlen(data); i++) {
           
            image_data[j] = data[i]; //copy the partial data of the image to the main variable of the image
            j++;
        }

        j = (int) strlen(image_data); 

        read(socket, &receiving, sizeof(int)); //Read if the image is still sending
    }

    image_to_directory(path, image_data); //Copy image to directory
}
```

This compiles and runs fine, but when I check the directory on the server side where the image has been stored, I can see it's not the same image as the client has sent (I confirmed via md5sum and hashes are not equal).

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: `strlen(img_data)` and `strlen(data)` are wrong. String functions can only be used for strings and not binary data. Use the return value of `read` instead to get the number of bytes read/received.

Comment: `read()` returns `-1` in case of an error, not 0. You have to test for `<=0`.

Comment: Not your problem, since i assume the server and client run on similar machines, but `int` can have a different size on the server and client. Better use `uint32_t` or something like that.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 what line do you refer to? Doesn't `while (n > 0)` accomplish that?

Comment: `while (n > 0)` is too late. If `read` returns `-1` the code continues and uses the result of `read` before it gets a chance to exit the loop. The actual incorrect check being referred to is `if (!n)`

Comment: I edited the code changing `strlens` to the return of the `reads`. It's still not working though

Comment: Do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger and step thru the code line by line to see where things start going wrong. For example, Look at the `j` value in the server code: `j++; ... j += size;` See a problem there? If you do proper debugging you should be able to find incorrect behaviour like this.

Comment: Is the endianness on the receiving side the same as the sending side?  (This is probably not your issue right now, but is a bug waiting to happen when you fix everything else.)

Comment: You're writing a sentinel 0 at the end, but it seems that your receiver is treating that value as part of the data if the final block written is not exactly 100 bytes.  There is no point sending the 1/0 values.  If you're going to send a count, instead of 1 you should send a block size.  (That is, if you're going to send 178 bytes total, send 100, then 100 bytes, then 78, then 78 bytes, and then the terminal 0).

Comment: Even when you are using `uint32_t` it is possible that server and client has different endiannes. Look at functions like `htonl()`

Comment: It is good to change your offline code based on discussion here, but Please Do Not edit contents of code in original post for reasons other than formatting.  When you _change the basic syntax_ that defines how the code worked at the time you posted the question it results in a moving target,  adds confusion to others attempting to address the original question and invalidates some of the suggestions people have made addressing the problem.  I have rolled the code back to its original content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `strlen` for your binary data length calculations. It is intended only for terminated *strings* (thus the name). You also have highly-ill-advised naked calls to read/write, which is a recipe for disaster when sending data over sockets.

You never seem to be sending more than 100 bytes at a time, which is helpful in this case to develop a more solid *protocol*. Consider this:

1. First octet is a `uint8_t` *byte count* N, and will be in 0..100.
2. Following the byte count, N bytes are transferred.
3. Repeat 1-2 until no more bytes remain.
4. Notify the server of EOF by sending a single zero-octet

An example of this sender code is shown here.

```
void send_image(const char *path, int socket)
{
    int fd = open(path, O_RDONLY); //I open the file of the image.jpg
    if (fd == -1)
        return;

    ssize_t n = 0;
    do
    {
        // note the first octet will prefix the length
        uint8_t img_data[101];
        n = read(fd, img_data+1, 100);
        if (n > 0)
        {
            // you never know  just how many bytes are going to
            // be sent, so setup the frame, but then ensure even
            // piecewise deliver can succeed.
            img_data[0] = (uint8_t)n;
            ssize_t sent = 0;
            size_t pos = 0;
            do
            {
                sent = write(socket, img_data+pos, (n+1)-pos);
                if (sent < 0)
                    break;
                pos += sent;
            } while ( pos < (n+1) && sent > 0);
        }

    } while (n > 0);

    uint8_t done = 0;
    write(socket, &done, sizeof done); // not much we can do if this fails

    close(fd);
}
```

I make no claims the above code will even compile, but the concept should be fairly obvious. That's it, however. Obviously there is more that could/should be done (checksums, restart options, etc.), but that's the basic premise.

The server side can do something similar, which I leave as an exercise for you. The point of all of this is to utilize the return values from your read/write calls. They're there for a reason. If you find yourself coding a "naked" read or write (where you don't gather the result of function and utilize it in some way), chances are you've done something horribly wrong.